# How do I set up my nginx files to connect to my server?

Tags: mysql, node.js, nginx, routes

I have a MySQL database and React front end that work in development using a Node server to connect the two. I have a VPS that I just created and am using Nginx to control the integration. Unfortunately, I am new to this and can't connect to the Node server when it's running on the box. I know it's listening on the correct port because `netstat -tulpn` shows it is (see below).

[image: server port]

I can connect directly to the MySQL database via SSH from my laptop so I know that's working properly. Like I said, the front end loads but can't connect to the server to log in (see below).

[image: 404 error]

I suspect I have made an error with my Nginx configuration but after trying various ideas for the past five hours, I'm at a loss.

Nginx default.conf

```
server {
    listen         443 default_server ssl;
    #listen        [::]:443 default_server ssl;
    server_name    thesystem.co.za;

    #ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/thesystem.co.za/fullchain.pem;
    #ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/thesystem.co.za/privkey.pem;

    expires       0;
    add_header    Cache-Control  public;
    add_header    Cache-Control  no-store;
    add_header    Cache-Control  no-cache;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header 'Referrer-Policy' 'origin';
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header Set-Cookie "HTTPOnly; HttpOnly; Secure";

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/thesystem;
    }

    location /integration/ {
       charset_types application/json;
       charset UTF-8;
       proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/api/;
    }
}
```

If anyone is able to offer some insight as to what I'm doing wrong, I would really appreciate. I have a test client starting in a few hours and I'm stuck at the last hurdle!

**** UPDATE ******
If I hit the server directly using curl when I'm logged on to the box, I get a response so I know it is listening. I must be doing something wrong with the nginx config like I said but I don't know what...

**** Included nginx.conf
nginx.conf

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    #large_client_header_buffers 16 64k;
    #client_max_body_size 100M;

    # Added By Willie for security
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers On;
    ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+CHACHA20:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS;
    # Added By Willie, hide Nginx version
    server_tokens off;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";


    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_min_length 1100;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types
        text/plain
        text/css
        text/js
        text/xml
        text/javascript
        application/javascript
        application/x-javascript
        application/json
        application/xml
        application/rss+xml
        image/svg+xml;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

*** Second update ***
I've reduced the `default.conf` to the bare minimum and it doesn't redirect to the proper location for the webpage or the server. All I get served is a 404 page.

```
server {
    listen         80 default_server;
    server_name    thesystem.co.za;


    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/thesystem;
    }

    location /integration/ {
       charset_types application/json;
       charset UTF-8;
       proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/;
       proxy_set_header Proxy "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using the `charset_types` in your http header? Is it nginx or your nodejs application returning the 404? Put something static and URL independent in `location /integration` as a test.

Comment: Yes, I am using `charset_types` in my header, it's set to `application/json`. I"m not sure how to put something static there but will try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there was nothing wrong with my nginx configuration. My host provider hadn't updated the DNS records properly so it was pointing to the website instead of the VPS!

If anyone else runs into the same problem, check here to ensure the `Remote Address` is correct. All I did was copy and paste it into my browser and when I ended up somewhere else, I knew something was wrong.

[image: Remote Address]

Thank you for your help, everyone, especially @dunhuang

Answer (score 0):

what's your local api path?  is it like `http://localhost:8081/api/admin/session`?

Usually it is because of the wrong `proxy_pass` route config. sometimes it is with or without slash problem. sometimes the alias name is not correct...

Change the ``proxy_pass```,
then you can access to

```
https://thesystem.co.za/integration/api/admin/sessions/
```

nginx.conf:

```
    location /integration/ {
       #....
       proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, that's correct. If I run `curl http://localhost:8081/api/admin/clients` on the server, I get a response. My database falls over with some complaint about a directory it needs to make but that's another problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem remains

Comment: I've add the nginx.conf file to my original post for reference.

Error log
`
2020/07/27 03:28:49 [error] 1496#0: *5 no "ssl_certificate" is defined in server listening on SSL port while SSL handshaking, client: 196.49.19.32, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2020/07/27 03:43:44 [error] 1496#0: *6 no "ssl_certificate" is defined in server listening on SSL port while SSL handshaking, client: 51.178.78.153, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2020/07/27 05:04:04 [notice] 2847#0: signal process started
2020/07/27 05:13:02 [notice] 2922#0: signal process started
`

Comment: I meant ```error.log```, usually under nginx's root dir, which help you to identify which exact route is 404 in your local service.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that was what I had posted for you. These are all the files I have in the nginx directory

conf.d                fastcgi_params          mime.types          scgi_params           win-utf
default.d             fastcgi_params.default  mime.types.default  scgi_params.default
fastcgi.conf          koi-utf                 nginx.conf          uwsgi_params
fastcgi.conf.default  koi-win                 nginx.conf.default  uwsgi_params.default

Comment: Uncomment the ssl_certificate file. and is there anything log about 404 ?

Comment: That's probably not good...

[emerg] BIO_new_file("/etc/letsencrypt/live/thesystem.co.za/fullchain.pem") failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('/etc/letsencrypt/live/thesystem.co.za/fullchain.pem','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

Comment: I'm trying to do that now with certbot but it keeps failing. I'll let you know when I get it right.

Comment: I've logged a ticket with the VPS host as I keep getting failures with the certificate installation.

From certbot:
To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address.

Comment: is that your local machine ?

Comment: No, I'm using an SSH connection to the Linux box. Sorry, did you mean the server when you asked if it was the local machine? I'm not familiar with all the terminology just yet...

Comment: ok...or you can skip listening 443, just ```listen 80``` instead

Comment: Whilst I wait for the support team to get back to me, I deleted the files I had uploaded to the /public_html folder. It looks like the entire nginx file is being ignored as now I get a 404 error for the front end too! It's clearly not picking up the locations it should be looking for.

Comment: The DNS record is correctly configured but I still get the error in certbot...?